# Github/Git ignore list - .gitignore file when files in same folder case

Tags: git, github, gitignore

```
public
    |--- user_thumbnail
        |---- 1.png
        |---- 2.png
        |---- 3.png
       ...    (num).png
        |---- default.png
```

The image name with number dynamically generate.

How could I git add the 'default.png', but don't add the (num).png in the .gitignore ?

---

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this perhaps?

```
public/user_thumbnail/*.png
!public/user_thumbnail/default.png
```

The Git manual describes the [syntax of the `.gitignore` patterns](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).